# Return only the latest record in relation with conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this relation:

```
public function latestEvent(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'client_id', 'id')
                ->whereIn('status', ['completed', 'waiting'])
                ->latest('start');
}
```

When I run this query

```
$patients = User::with('status', 'userMeta', 'latestEvent', 'latestEvent.employee', 'latestEvent.procedure')->whereHas('role', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'client');
        });

$patients->whereHas('latestEvent', function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('procedure_id', $request->get('procedurе_filter'));
});

$patients = $patients->orderBy('created_at', $order)->paginate(10);
```

I get mixed results. If the user had events with the matching procedure_id in the past they also gets into the results although it is not the latest event of the user.

Then I tried changing the relation to this:

```
return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'client_id', 'id')
                    ->whereIn('status', ['completed', 'waiting'])
                    ->latestOfMany();
```

I though it worked, but when I created new event for the user (the event had status "upcoming" so it did not met the whereIn condition) the results when the relation was called was NULL. It seems like latestOfMany() always gets the highest ID and ignores the where condition.

How can I efficiently perform this task of filtering users by their latest event procedure_id? The user may have hundreds of events but I want to filter by the latest "completed" or "waiting" event. The datetime of the event is stored in "start" column.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasOne` relationship can be tricky in situations like this. I don't understand the one-to-one relationship much to diagnose the problem. But I know an alternative that might work for you.

We can [select from a sub query](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#subquery-selects):

```php
return User::addSelect([
        'latest_event_procedure_id' => Flight::select('procedure_id')
            ->whereColumn('client_id', 'users.id')]
            ->whereIn('status', ['completed', 'waiting'])
            ->orderByDesc('start'))
    ])
    ->with(
        'status',
        'userMeta',
        'latestEvent',
        'latestEvent.employee',
        'latestEvent.procedure'
    )
    ->whereHas('role', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'client');
    })
    ->having('latest_event_procedure_id', request('procedurе_filter'))
    ->orderBy('created_at', $order)
    ->paginate(10);
```

You could be interested in the following resources:

- [Dynamic relationships](https://reinink.ca/articles/dynamic-relationships-in-laravel-using-subqueries)
- [Laracasts lesson 3](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-performance-patterns/episodes/3)
- [Laracasts lesson 4](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-performance-patterns/episodes/4)